# Configure ssl for the web services

Tags: asp.net, web-services, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

All, I was trying to enable my web service for ssl(self-signed certificate) by following this [instructions](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/06/tip-trick-enabling-ssl-on-iis7-using-self-signed-certificates.aspx). But so far I get stuck with it without answer.

One thing I thought the writer missed is not set `Advanced setting->Enabled Protocols=https`. I think it is necessary. 
And In my case, I need to encrypt the data transported between client and server. So I thought I need to set `ssl setting->client certificate:required`.(Should I do that?) Just like below.

[image]

and I had set the ssl port is `7002` for my web services. and specified the new created self-signed certificate for my web services. just like below.

[image]

The web services started successfully. But when I accessed the url with `https://localhost:7002/xxx.asmx`.
I got a error message says :

> HTTP Error 403.7 - Forbidden The page you are attempting to access
>   requires your browser to have a Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) client
>   certificate that the Web server recognizes.

I don't If I did something wrong or missed something important . please kindly tell me if you found it .thanks.

My computer is Win7 64 bit OS, and IIS 7.0.

Comment: After reading this [post](http://forums.iis.net/t/1156197.aspx), I think if I just need encrypt the data transported between client and server by ssl I just only need the `Accept` option, Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must uncheck the "Require" option below client certificates by selecting "Accept" or "Ignore" instead. By selecting "Require" you expect the client - the explorer/firefox whatever browser you have - to have a certificate that you trust in it's certificate store.

Requiring the client to have a certificate is known as mutual authentication and is unnecessary to achieve traffic encryption.

In mutual SSL there are four main components, 
(1) the trust chain for the server, 
(2) the trust chain for the client, 
(3) the client certificate, 
(4) the server certificate.

Certificates (3 & 4) will have trust chains (1 & 2) - which may be the same, a "root CA" and commonly a chain of "intermediate CA" that sign each other in sequence to establish their authenticity, the root signs the intermediate which in turn signs the intermediate above it and so on until the last one in the chain signs the certificate. A self signed certificate signs itself and is therefore both a certificate and a trust chain. In the case of a non self signed server certificate you expect the trust chain to be available on the client so that it can validate the provenance of the certificate by checking it's signature. In mutual authentication you also require the server to have the trust chain of the client so that it can check it's provenance.

Comment: I think you mean the `require` option below the `client certificate`? right ?

Comment: This is not a check box , it a radio button .It can't be unchecked. Please correct you answer. thanks.

Comment: Hi, Paddy Carroll, `By selecting "Require" you expect the client - the explorer/firefox whatever browser you have - to have a certificate that you trust in it's certificate store.`,little confused by it . how many certificates are involved in mutual ssl? thanks.