# Write HTTPS web service in asp.net and call it from android

Tags: android, asp.net, web-services

I have to write a web service in ASP.NET and an android application which takes a list from it by providing a username and password pair and finally show the result in a listview. This communication should takes place in SSL manner. Which web service model I must use? Is there any tutorial for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Solution will be splitted into two parts :

1- creating Https web service

Steps in brief:

- normally you create web site using Visual Studio
- add web services to web site
- deploy it in iis
- Install Server Certificates on the Web Server Step
- Create  a Simple Web Service
- Configure the Web Service Virtual Directory to Require SSL
- Test the Web Service Using a Browser

Tutorials & References :

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649205.aspx
- [Configure ssl for the web services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16768454/configure-ssl-for-the-web-services)
- https://rmanimaran.wordpress.com/2010/06/24/creating-and-using-c-web-service-over-https-%E2%80%93-ssl-2/
- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/324069?wa=wsignin1.0

2- Consuming https web services in android app :

i dont have much experiences in android app but i found a lot of tutorials explain the trick of consuming https services in android app

Tutorials & References :

- https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html
- http://www.mobiledevguide.com/2013/07/how-to-access-https-web-service-in.html
- https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/mobile-development/threads/367301/android-webservices-via-ksoap2-https
- http://www.ipragmatech.com/secure-rest-web-service-mobile-application-android.html#.VTyMuSGqqko

i hope this help you 
happy Coding :)

Comment: most of them use a fake trust manager because they use application in trusted network!!! but I want to use my app in internet so fake trust manager is not a good solution for me.

Comment: could you tell me errors you got after doing these steps?

Comment: there is no error!!! my problem is with using fake trust manager which allow all SSL communication takes place in the android app.

Comment: i told you that i don't have much experience on android dev  but i want to help
check this article carefuly https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html